# Remover atributo de objeto

Tags: javascript, typescript

Supongamos que tengo:

```
let test = {id:1, name:'test', age: 13, telephone: 66666}
```

y quiero eliminar de ese objeto el id y telephone

Nota: no puedo igualarlos a null, ni crear un nuevo objeto que le pase solo name y age

Resultado deseado:

```
test = {name:'test', age: 13}
```

Comment: Una búsqueda rápida en el sitio arroja resultado. Tu pregunta es duplicada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre la solución:

```
  delete test.name
  delete test.telephone
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: Justo estaba redactando :)

Comment: jeje no sabia como buscarlo y al final de mirar tanto lo encontré, gracias de todas formas

Comment: Puedes enriquecer tu respuesta agregando un link a la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete). Haz clic en [edit] para ello. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el operador 'delete':

```javascript
let test = {id: 1, name: 'test', age: 13, telephone: 66666};

// Eliminar propiedades "id" y "telephone"
delete test.id;
delete test.telephone;

console.log(test); // Resultado deseado: {name: 'test', age: 13}
```